# Eve (Python) takes a long time to return a filtered query but is quick on non-filtered queries?

Tags: mongodb, eve

I'm using Eve as a REST API server to interface with MongoDB.

Running:
`GET /year_origin_destination_hs07_4?where={}` is nearly instantaneous (it returns the first page of a collection with 33M items).

By contrast, running: `GET /year_origin_destination_hs07_4?where={"origin": "chn"}` takes almost 18 seconds to return (the first page of 956k items).

Can anyone explain why this is taking **disproportionately** longer? Filtering for this connection in MongoDB takes very little time.

MongoDB example: `db.year_origin_destination_hs07_4.find({origin: "chn"})` < 1s returning paginated results

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had to enable this flag: `OPTIMIZE_PAGINATION_FOR_SPEED`.

Reason why is here: [Python Eve Documentation](http://python-eve.org/config.html)

> Set this to True to improve pagination performance. When optimization is active no count operation, which can be slow on large collections, is performed on the database. This does have a few consequences. Firstly, no document count is returned. Secondly, HATEOAS is less accurate: no last page link is available, and next page link is always included, even on last page. On big collections, switching this feature on can greatly improve performance. Defaults to False (slower performance; document count included; accurate HATEOAS).